# How to delete S3 objects/versions on MFA protected bucket using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a versioned S3 bucket named `protected-bucket` and I want to programmatically delete objects or versions (sometimes just some versions). Bucket has the following policy attached that enforces the MFA to be present when Delete* actions are about to be executed:

```
{
    "Sid": "RequireMFAForDelete",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "s3:Delete*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::protected-bucket/*",
    "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
            "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the `"Condition": { "Null": { "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": true }}` in bucket policy, as suggested on the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-7 page. Got the same problem from below...

Here is a minimal Python3 code that is supposed to delete object version in the bucket I mentioned above:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
from datetime import datetime


mfa_totp = input("Enter the MFA code: ")

session_name='my-test-session-' + str(int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()))
client=boto3.client('sts', 'us-east-1')
ar_res = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::123456789102:role/test-role',
    RoleSessionName=session_name,
    DurationSeconds=900,
    SerialNumber='arn:aws:iam::987654321098:mfa/my_user_name',
    TokenCode=mfa_totp,
)
print(ar_res)
tmp_creds = ar_res["Credentials"]

s3_client = boto3.client("s3", "us-east-1",
                         aws_access_key_id=tmp_creds["AccessKeyId"],
                         aws_secret_access_key=tmp_creds["SecretAccessKey"],
                         aws_session_token=tmp_creds["SessionToken"])

s3_bucket = "protected-bucket"
s3_key = "test/test4.txt"
s3_version = "XYZXbHbi3lpCNlOM8peIim6gi.IZQJqM"

# If I put code here that lists objects in 
if s3_version:
    response = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=s3_bucket,
                                       Key=s3_key,
                                       VersionId=s3_version)
else:
    response = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=s3_bucket,Key=s3_key)

print(response)
```

The error I am getting follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./del_test.py", line 37, in <module>
    response = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=s3_bucket,
  File "/home/dejan/py/myproj/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/dejan/py/myproj/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
```

Few things to note:

- Role I am assuming is a different account (some people may have noticed different account numbers in the Python code.
- That Role has Delete* actions allowed in a policy attached to the role. When I remove the MFA protection in the bucket policy, the Python 3 code above works - it can delete objects and versions.

Comment: The documentation says that `TokenCode` is "The value provided by the MFA device, if the trust policy of the role being assumed requires MFA." Does the trust policy of that role require MFA? It is possible that MFA on a Role doesn't translate down to MFA for the actual API calls. You might need to call [`get_session_token()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token) to authenticate with the MFA device.

Comment: I suspected the same, but I do not know how to confirm my suspicions... I need to assume role, as only that role can delete objects in the bucket. So do you propose I use get_session_token(), and then assume role with credentials returned? I was always under impression assume_role() does the same with only difference being few additional parameters (role to assume, etc)...

Comment: You'd probably need to do the reverse... Assume the IAM Role with the necessary permissions, then GetSessionToken that keeps the same set of permissions but allows an MFA token to be specified. Then, use the resulting credentials to perform the Delete.

Comment: `GetSessionToken` cannot be called with session credentials. I believe It's the other way round: get MFA session first then pass these credentials to a new STS client to do `AssumeRole`, then use those new credentials for deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I missed the key piece of information given in the https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html document:

> The temporary credentials returned by AssumeRole do not include MFA information in the context, so you cannot check individual API operations for MFA. This is why you must use GetSessionToken to restrict access to resources protected by resource-based policies.

In short, if I just assume_role(), *with* MFA, like I did in the Python code presented in the question, the MFA data will not be passed down, so get_session_token() is a must... Following refactored code (made with help of my colleague @Chadwick) works as expected:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
from datetime import datetime


mfa_serial = "arn:aws:iam::987654321098:mfa/my_user_name"
role_to_assume = "arn:aws:iam::123456789102:role/test-role"

mfa_totp = input("Enter the MFA code: ")
mfa_sts_client = boto3.client("sts", "us-east-1")
mfa_credentials = mfa_sts_client.get_session_token(
    SerialNumber=mfa_serial,
    TokenCode=mfa_totp,
)["Credentials"]

session_name='my-test-session-' + str(int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()))
# We now create a client with credentials from the MFA enabled session we created above:
ar_sts_client=boto3.client("sts", "us-east-1",
                           aws_access_key_id=mfa_credentials["AccessKeyId"],
                           aws_secret_access_key=mfa_credentials["SecretAccessKey"],
                           aws_session_token=mfa_credentials["SessionToken"])
ar_res = ar_sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_to_assume,
    RoleSessionName=session_name,
    DurationSeconds=900
)
print(ar_res)
tmp_creds = ar_res["Credentials"]

s3_client = boto3.client("s3", "us-east-1",
                         aws_access_key_id=tmp_creds["AccessKeyId"],
                         aws_secret_access_key=tmp_creds["SecretAccessKey"],
                         aws_session_token=tmp_creds["SessionToken"])


s3_bucket = "protected-bucket"
s3_key = "test/test4.txt"
s3_version = "YYFMqnLaVEosoZ1Zk3Xy8dVbNGQVEF35"
# s3_version = None

if s3_version:
    response = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=s3_bucket,
                                       Key=s3_key,
                                       VersionId=s3_version)
else:
    response = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=s3_bucket,Key=s3_key)

print(response)
```